# How to get the page path which is loading a html page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a page `app/BlockA/page1.html`, in that I'm loading another page

i.e `$("#div1").load("app/Common/sample.html").`

same I have in `app/BlockB/page2.html`

This child page is loaded successfully from both pages ,

now  after loading sample.html based on the parent page i.e BlockA/page1.html or BlockB/page2.html I have a custom functionality .

How to determine from which page my child page is loaded ???

i.e I would like to get the parent page url i.e absolute path like whether `BlockA/page1.html or BlockB/page2.html`

Note: Using window.loaction.href gives the url i.e `http://localhost:5012/masterpage.hmtl` , which I don't want. This is a **single page application**

Comment: Use window.location.href.

Comment: Why do you need that? Possible solution: write a js variable in the main page and access it in the childs pahe code

Comment: then you're going to have to show more code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `window.location.href` to get the URL of the parent page.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the window.location and create your functionality based on what result is returned.

```
$(function(){
    var loc = window.location.href;
    if(loc.indexOf('page1') > 0) {
        // do stuff
    }
    else { //do other things or check for other pages
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

if i understood correctly use `document.referrer`